# Tic Tac Toe using C

Tags: c

Brief Explanation of the Problem - The aim of the code is to make a basic tic tac toe game using C. There are two players `X` and `O` , both can enter various numbers as `choice` from 1-9 for each individual chance.
The game board is similar to a **3 x 3** matrix, where -

1. Row 1 is for 1 to 3.
2. Row 2 is for 4 to 6.
3. Row 3 is for 7 to 9.

Any number except 1-9 will throw an error and will prompt the user to re-enter the number. Unfortunately, I'm getting the same Invalid input error for a valid input. Everything else seems to work except my loop.

***Here's the code for reference -***

```
#include<stdio.h>     //Tic Tac Toe
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

char square[10] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
int choice, player;

int checkForWin();
void displayBoard();
void mrkBoard(char mark);

int main()
{
 int i;
 char mark;
 player = 1;
 do
 {
  displayBoard();
  player = (player % 2) ? 1:2;
  printf("Player %d, enter the number: ",player);
  scanf("%d",&choice);
  mark = (player == 1) ? 'X' : 'O';
  mrkBoard(mark);
  i = checkForWin();
  player++;
 }while(i == -1);
 return 0;
}

int checkForWin()
{
  int returnValue = 0;
  if (square[1] == square[2] && square[2] == square[3])
  {
    returnValue = 1;
  }
  else if (square[4] == square[5] && square[5] == square[6])
   returnValue = 1;
  else if (square[7] == square[8] && square[8] == square[9])
   returnValue = 1;
  else if (square[1] == square[5] && square[5] == square[9])
  returnValue = 1;
  else if (square[3] == square[5] && square[5] == square[7])
  returnValue = 1;
  else if (square[1] == square[4] && square[4] == square[7])
  returnValue = 1;
  else if (square[2] == square[5] && square[5] == square[8])
  returnValue = 1;
  else if (square[3] == square[6] && square[6] == square[9])
  returnValue = 1;
  else if(square[1] != '1' && square[2] != '2' && square[3] != '3' && square[4] != '4' &&
  square[5] != '5' && square[6] != '6' && square[7] != '7' &&
  square[8] != '8' && square[9] != '9')
  returnValue = 0;
  else
  returnValue = -1;
  return returnValue;
}

void displayBoard()
{
  system("cls");
  printf("\n\nTic Tac Toe\n\n");

  printf("Player 1 (X) - Player 2 (O)\n\n\n");

  printf("     |     |     \n");
  printf("  %c  |  %c  |  %c \n", square[1], square[2],square[3]);

  printf("_____|_____|_____\n");
  printf("     |     |     \n");

  printf("  %c  |  %c  |  %c\n", square[4], square[5],square[6]);

  printf("_____|_____|_____\n");
  printf("     |     |     \n");

  printf("  %c  |  %c  |  %c\n", square[7], square[8],square[9]);
  printf("     |     |     \n\n");
}

void mrkBoard(char mark)
{
 if (choice == 1 && square[1] == '1')
 square[1] = mark;
 else if (choice == 2 && square[1] == '2')
 square[2] = mark;
 else if (choice == 3 && square[1] == '3')
 square[3] = mark;
 else if (choice == 4 && square[1] == '4')
 square[4] = mark;
 else if (choice == 5 && square[1] == '5')
 square[5] = mark;
 else if (choice == 6 && square[1] == '6')
 square[6] = mark;
 else if (choice == 7 && square[1] == '7')
 square[7] = mark;
 else if (choice == 8 && square[1] == '8')
 square[8] = mark;
 else if (choice == 9 && square[1] == '9')
 square[9] = mark;

 else
 {
   printf("Invalid ");
   player--;
   getch();
 }
}
```

Comment: What's with `&& square[1] == '1'` ... `&& square[1] == '2'`... `&& square[1] == '3'`?? Why does the `1` never change? I mean `square[1] != '2'` by `char square[10] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};` You can't use any input function correctly without checking the return, e.g. `if (scanf("%d",&choice) != 1) { fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr); return 1; }`. Also you can do `displayBoard()` with a single `printf()` -- no need for a separate function call per-line of output.

Comment: Thanks man, I found the bug

Comment: Glad to help -- we've all been there...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin My code now works fine, can you elaborate a bit more on  *Also you can do `displayBoard()` with a single `printf()` -- no need for a separate function call per-line of output*

Comment: I'm still learning so I wanted to write cleaner and concise codes

Comment: Two things: Firstly, extract a [mcve]. This will help you focus on the problem. Secondly, use a debugger to step through the code. This is an invaluable skill, allowing you to observe your program in action.

Comment: No worries, you can simply do `printf("\n\nTic Tac Toe\n\n"` then next line `"Player 1 (X) - Player 2 (O)\n\n\n"` then next line `"Player 1 (X) - Player 2 (O)\n\n\n"` ... on until the last `"     |     |     \n\n", square[1], square[2],square[3], square[4], square[5],square[6], square[7], square[8],square[9]);` (you can indent your board output any way you want -- line it up so it looks nice) All adjacent string literals are concatenated during compilation. One call to `printf()` is much more efficient than 11.

Comment: See [Only one printf() required](https://paste.opensuse.org/36080046)

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate the help

Comment: Here is a [Full - One printf()](https://paste.opensuse.org/99369016) example that shows how to eliminate the use of the global array `squares[]` by passing it as a parameter to `displayBoard()` -- Good luck with your coding.

Comment: Tip: As `char sqaure[]` is nearly a _string_ (lacks a _null character_), make it one with `char square[10+1] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9', '\0'};`.   Then a simple debug print could be `puts(square)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>     //Tic Tac Toe
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

char square[10] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
int choice, player;
int checkForWin();
void displayBoard();
void mrkBoard(char mark);

int main()
{
 int i;
 char mark;
 player = 1;
 do
 {
  displayBoard();
  player = (player % 2) ? 1:2;
  printf("Player %d, enter the number: ",player);
  scanf("%d",&choice);
  mark = (player == 1) ? 'X' : 'O';
  mrkBoard(mark);
  i = checkForWin();
  player++;
 }while(i == -1);
 return 0;
}

int checkForWin()
{
  int returnValue = 0;
  if (square[1] == square[2] && square[2] == square[3])
  {
    returnValue = 1;
  }
  else if (square[4] == square[5] && square[5] == square[6])
   returnValue = 1;
  else if (square[7] == square[8] && square[8] == square[9])
   returnValue = 1;
  else if (square[1] == square[5] && square[5] == square[9])
  returnValue = 1;
  else if (square[3] == square[5] && square[5] == square[7])
  returnValue = 1;
  else if (square[1] == square[4] && square[4] == square[7])
  returnValue = 1;
  else if (square[2] == square[5] && square[5] == square[8])
  returnValue = 1;
  else if (square[3] == square[6] && square[6] == square[9])
  returnValue = 1;
  else if(square[1] != '1' && square[2] != '2' && square[3] != '3' && square[4] != '4' &&
  square[5] != '5' && square[6] != '6' && square[7] != '7' &&
  square[8] != '8' && square[9] != '9')
  returnValue = 0;
  else
  returnValue = -1;
  return returnValue;
}

void displayBoard()
{
  system("cls");
  printf("\n\nTic Tac Toe\n\n");

  printf("Player 1 (X) - Player 2 (O)\n\n\n");

  printf("     |     |     \n");
  printf("  %c  |  %c  |  %c \n", square[1], square[2],square[3]);

  printf("_____|_____|_____\n");
  printf("     |     |     \n");

  printf("  %c  |  %c  |  %c\n", square[4], square[5],square[6]);

  printf("_____|_____|_____\n");
  printf("     |     |     \n");

  printf("  %c  |  %c  |  %c\n", square[7], square[8],square[9]);
  printf("     |     |     \n\n");
}

void mrkBoard(char mark)
{
 if (choice == 1 && square[1] == '1')
 square[1] = mark;
 else if (choice == 2 && square[2] == '2')
 square[2] = mark;
 else if (choice == 3 && square[3] == '3')
 square[3] = mark;
 else if (choice == 4 && square[4] == '4')
 square[4] = mark;
 else if (choice == 5 && square[5] == '5')
 square[5] = mark;
 else if (choice == 6 && square[6] == '6')
 square[6] = mark;
 else if (choice == 7 && square[7] == '7')
 square[7] = mark;
 else if (choice == 8 && square[8] == '8')
 square[8] = mark;
 else if (choice == 9 && square[9] == '9')
 square[9] = mark;

 else
 {
   printf("Invalid ");
   player--;
   getch();
 }
}
```